# Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements.... in content_builder.php line 164

Tags: php, wordpress

```
Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\xampp\htdocs\cat-cafe\wp-content\themes\grandrestaurant\modules\content_builder.php on line 164
```

I was creating a page by using default content builder in wordpress and I encountered the above error & also content is not even getting save while updating.

The code content_builder.php is(line in which error is occuring):

```
if(!empty($ppb_form_data_order[0]))
    {
        $count_ppb = count($ppb_form_data_order[0]);
    }
```

Is there any solution through which I can tackle this problem..!?

Wordpress version : 4.9.8
PHP version : 7.2.7

Comment: `$ppb_form_data_order[0]` is not implementing `Countable`. Check the type of the entry like this: `var_dump(gettype($ppb_form_data_order[0]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test variable before use it :

```
if(isset($ppb_form_data_order) && is_array($ppb_form_data_order))
{
    $count_ppb = count($ppb_form_data_order);
}
```

Or like your post under first entry

```
if(isset($ppb_form_data_order[0]) && is_array($ppb_form_data_order[0]))
{
    $count_ppb = count($ppb_form_data_order[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thanx  its working fine!!  Hope it won’t give any problem after making it live ..

Answer (score 0):

You does to check if $ppb_form_data_order[0] is an array :

```
if(!empty($ppb_form_data_order[0]))    {

  if( is_array($ppb_form_data_order[0]) ){
    $count_ppb = count($ppb_form_data_order[0]);
    }
    else{
    $count_ppb = 0;
    }
}
```